# viewer to display the floorplan?

Tags: gnuplot, dot

I have a format which describes rectangles and connectivity between them.

for example:
( rect name width height location_coordinates )

```
rect b 10 10     0 0
rect f 10 10     0 10
rect k 20 10     0 20
rect c 10 10     10 0
rect g 10 10     10 10
rect e 10 10     20 0
rect d 10 10     20 10
rect a 10 10     20 20


edge b f 
edge b g
edge b c
edge f k
edge f g
edge g c
edge k g 
edge g a
edge g d 
edge g c
edge d e
edge d a
edge d e
edge d k
```

So for this I would like to get something like this:

[image]

Can I draw something similar using .dot/gnuplot format(or there are some other formats suitable for this case)?

I have looked over it, but cannot find a way how  for example place rectangle in a specific location or how to connect rectangle centers.

Comment: No, you can't plot such a file with gnuplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preprocess your data as follows, using awk or your favourite language

For each rectangle:

- print x+y coordinates of its lower left corner
- print x+y coordinates of its upper left corner
- print x+y coordinates of its upper right corner
- print x+y coordinates of its lower right corner
- print x+y coordinates of its lower left corner
- print a blank line (to suppress the connection between rectangles)

Plot this file `with lines`.

#### Write the edges into a second file

For each edge:

- print x+y coordinates of midpoint of first rectangle
- print x+y coordinates of midpoint of second rectangle
- print blank line

Plot this file `with lines`.

#### Write the labels into a third file (x, y, label)

Plot them `with labels`.